# MDX: multiple KEYx dimension properties behave strangely

Tags: mdx, olap

There are some values in a cube having complex key (e.g., `[Period].[Fiscal].[FMonth].&[2000]&[7]`). Sometimes I need to receive this key.

In other cases (with simple key) I did it like `SELECT [dimension].[hierarchy].[level] DIMENSION PROPERTIES KEY0` and everything was fine, but when I tried to execute `SELECT [Period].[Fiscal].[FMonth] DIMENSION PROPERTIES KEY0, KEY1` I've got two properties named [KEY0] both valued with key's second part. I still can get either KEY0 or KEY1 separately, but never at once.

What am I doing wrong? OLAP server is MS 2008.

Comment: That should work. Any chance you could let us know on the actual query you were using?

Comment: It happens with absolutely any query, even the simplest like `SELECT [Period].[Fiscal].[FMonth] DIMENSION PROPERTIES KEY0, KEY1 ON 0 FROM Cube`

Comment: Any chance you could use calculated members? I might have a solution for you then.

Comment: Yes, I definitely can